# Calculate the code complexity of below code

Tags: computation-theory

[image]

I feel that in worst case also, condition is true only two times when j=i or j=i^2 then loop runs for an extra i + i^2 times.
In worst case, if we take sum of inner 2 loops it will be  theta(i^2) + i + i^2  , which is equal to theta(i^2) itself;
Summation of theta(i^2) on outer loop gives theta(n^3).
So, is the answer theta(n^3) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the overall performance is `theta(n^4)`.  Here is your pseudo-code, given in text format:

```
for (i = 1 to n) do
    for (j = 1 to i^2) do
        if (j % i == 0) then
            for (k = 1 to j) do
                sum = sum + 1
```

Appreciate first that the `j % i == 0` condition will only be true when `j` is multiples of `n`.  This would occur in fact only `n` times, so the final inner `for` loop would only be hit `n` times coming from the `for` loop in `j`.  The final for loop would require `n^2` steps for the case where `j` is near the end of the range.  On the other hand, it would only take roughly `n` steps for the start of the range.  So, the overall performance here should be somewhere between `O(n^3)` and `O(n^4)`, but `theta(n^4)` should be valid.

Comment: Did you mean `i^2` instead of `n^2` in the second loop?

Comment: @danportin Yes I did, and thanks for the correction :-)

Answer (score 1):

For fixed `i`, the `i` integers `1 ≤ j ≤ i2` such that `j % i = 0` are `{i,2i,...,i2}`. It follows that the inner loop is executed `i` times with arguments `i * m` for `1 ≤ m ≤ i` and the guard executed `i2` times. Thus, the complexity function `T(n) ∈ Θ(n4)` is given by:

```
T(n) = ∑[i=1,n] (∑[j=1,i2] 1 + ∑[m=1,i] ∑[k=1,i*m] 1)
     = ∑[i=1,n] ∑[j=1,i2] 1 + ∑[i=1,n] ∑[m=1,i] ∑[k=1,i*m] 1
     = n3/3 + n2/2 + n/6 + ∑[i=1,n] ∑[m=1,i] ∑[k=1,i*m] 1
     = n3/3 + n2/2 + n/6 + n4/8 + 5n3/12 + 3n2/8 + n/12
     = n4/8 + 3n3/4 + 7n2/8 + n/4
```